# Loop through a set of elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to loop through 12 classes, named `.video-link0` through `video-link11`, where each one gets the treatment:

```
$('.video-link[n]').click(function() {
    $('.video-link[n]').addClass('show');
});
```

Essentially, I want the following behavior:

When `.video-link1` is clicked, `addClass('show')` to `video-link1`

When `.video-link2` is clicked, `addClass('show')` to `video-link2`

and so on, as if I had 12 functions that looked like this:

```
$('.video-link1').click(function() {
    $('.video-link1').addClass('show');
});

$('.video-link2').click(function() {
    $('.video-link2').addClass('show');
});

... and so on
```

I want to write a single loop that replaces the need to write this out as 12 separate cases.

The following does not yield the result I'm looking for:

```
var elems = 12;

for(var i = 0; i < elems; i++){
    $('.video-link' + i).click(function() {
        $('.video-link' + i).addClass('show');
    });
};
```

** **UPDATE** **

This is not a duplicate question, or else the above question referenced does not address my requirement. I am not trying to move up and down the DOM with `next`. Rather, I want to write a single loop that iterates through 12 classes numbered 0-11 using `i` to enumerate the cases.

** **UPDATE** **

This works for me, and is using a suggestion by Lloyd Banks (I needed the `i` enumerator PLUS the `this` keyword):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    $('.video-link'+i).click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('show');
    });
  }
```

Comment: Does each element have the classes `video-link video-link[n]` or just `video-link[n]`?

Comment: Can you put the html?

Comment: `$(".yourClassName").each(function(){ $(this).addClass('show');});`

Comment: So reference the current element, not all of them... `$(this).addClass(...)` The last code example is the infamous for loop.

Comment: @jesse-kernaghan, the classes are named `video-link[n]` as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
function(numberOfElements){
    for(var i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++){
        $('.video-link' + i).on('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass('show');
        });
    }
}
```

You should also be using the `.on` binding event instead of `.click`.  If you are generating your element after initial page load and use `.click`, the event handler wouldn't be registered.

Comment: `.on('click', func)` and `.click(func)` work the same way, one is just a shorthand for the other.

Comment: @lloyd-banks, I did in fact name my classes video-link1, video-link2, etc. I need a solution that accounts for this.

Comment: @amoeboar I went ahead and made changes to accommodate that

Comment: @JesseKernaghan You ***need*** to use `.on` if you are dynamically adding elements on your DOM.  Downvoting someone's answer when you are clearly wrong makes you look like a clown

Comment: @LloydBanks Not sure what to tell you, it's one of the first lines of the docs: "This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler )" http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @JesseKernaghan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click/11878976#11878976

Answer (score 2):

You can use starts with `^=` selector and reference each with `$(this)`

```
$("[class^='video-link']").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this)` to reference the current (targeted) element inside of a event callback:

```
$('.video-link').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('show');
});
```

Comment: I need a solution that calls `click` and `addClass` to classes named `video-link0` through `video-link11`.

Comment: @amoeboar I would suggest trying Maxali's answer, it should do what you need without needing any outside loop.

Comment: This is not the optimal way to register an event listener using jQuery.  You should always be using `.on` as opposed to `.click` for memory optimization and to add compatibility for dynamically created elements